# How to publish react native ios to appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to deploy to a reactnative app to appstore via a pipeline in app center, but i get the error:

`##[error]Error: {"code":"bad_request","message":"Error: Failed to publish to store. Application with id:xxxxxxxx could not be found in AppStore."}.`

Sure enough the id that it says does not exist, is not the appid I see for our app in appconnect.
I am new to the project and dont have access to the previous developer.

I see `provisioning profile and certificate` have been setup, should i delete the existing and setup my own?
Everything else works great including the build process, the only issue is with uploading build to appstore